# pseudovarieties and profinite group : do * and g() commute?

Tags: profinite-groups, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $V$ and $W$ be pseudovarieties  of finite monoids. We denote with $gV$ the pseudovariety of categories generated by $V$, and by $V*W$ the semidirect product of pseudovarieties $V$ and $W$.
Does the equality $g(V*W)=gV*gW$ hold?

Comment: What is $gV$? What is $g$?

Comment: @YCor, it is the pseudovariety of categories generated by the monoids in  V viewed as one-object categories.

Comment: Here it should be mentioned that semidirect products of categories are defined via the Grothendieck construction

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  This was proved by me in 
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404998001261

A cleaner proof is given in http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdfplus/10.1142/S021819670300150X

There were earlier proofs that were incomplete by Therien and also by either Jones or Trotter, I forget which.